# Switching between two NSWindows

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, switching

I am making a simple mac app in which i want to switch windows.
I have two NSWindowController class `MainWindow` and `DetailWindow`

I am using this code :

MainWindow class:

```
//MainWindow.h
@class DetailWindow;
@interface MainWindow : NSWindowController{

    IBOutlet NSButton *btn1;
    DetailWindow *detailwindow;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSButton *btn1;
- (IBAction)btn1Event:(id)sender;

//MainWindow.m

@implementation MainWindow
@synthesize btn1;

- (IBAction)btn1Event:(id)sender {

if (!detailwindow) {
    detailwindow = [[DetailWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DetailWindow"];

}
    [detailwindow showWindow:self];
}
@end
```

DetailWindow Class:

```
//DetailWindow.h
@class MainWindow;
@interface DetailWindow : NSWindowController{

    IBOutlet NSButton *backbtn;
    MainWindow *mainwindow;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSButton *backbtn;
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;

//DetailWindow.m

@implementation DetailWindow
@synthesize backbtn;

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {

if (!mainwindow) {
    mainwindow = [[MainWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];

}
    [mainwindow showWindow:self];
}
@end
```

Now the problem is when i click `backbtn on DetaiWindow` it will open a new `MainWindow`.
So i have two `MainWindow` on screen.
I want just main window at front when i click backbtn.

Any help??

Thank you..!!

Comment: where is `mainWindow` declared in `DetailWindow` class ?

Comment: After declaring `backbtn`.. let me edit question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that each window is assuming that it is its own job to create the other. Each has an ivar for the other, but there's no external access to it -- via a property or being an `IBOutlet` or anything else -- so it always starts out as `nil`, and a new copy gets created instead of reusing the old one.

There are any number of ways to get around this. Probably the easiest would be to create both windows in Interface Builder and link them up there, having made the ivars `IBOutlet`. Then you know you never have to create them in code at all.

However, purely on the basis of inertia, here's an alternative that sticks closer to what you've got already. Note that I've assumed for simplicity that `mainWindow` always exists first. If not, you'll have to duplicate the process the other way around.

```
//MainWindow.h
@class DetailWindow;
@interface MainWindow : NSWindowController
{

    IBOutlet NSButton *btn1;
    DetailWindow *detailwindow;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSButton *btn1;
- (IBAction)btn1Event:(id)sender;

//MainWindow.m

@implementation MainWindow
@synthesize btn1;

- (IBAction)btn1Event:(id)sender
{
    if (!detailwindow)
    {
        detailwindow = [[DetailWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DetailWindow"];

        // having created the other window, give it a reference back to this one
        detailWindow.mainWindow = self;
    }

    [detailwindow showWindow:self];
}
@end

//DetailWindow.h
@class MainWindow;
@interface DetailWindow : NSWindowController
{

    IBOutlet NSButton *backbtn;
    MainWindow *mainwindow;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSButton *backbtn;

// allow the main window to be set from outside
@property (nonatomic, retain) MainWindow *mainWindow;
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;

//DetailWindow.m

@implementation DetailWindow
@synthesize backbtn;
@synthesize mainWindow;

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    // no window creation on the way back
    NSAssert(mainWindow, "mainWindow not set!");
    [mainwindow showWindow:self];
}
@end
```

Untested, so usual caveats apply.

Comment: Thank you so much for all explanation walky-talky..!!  and this code is just working fine..!!:)

Answer (score -1):

You have to call orderFront: method with self object on main window.

To do this you must find a reference to the main window. A way to do this is:

```
[NSApp mainWindow];
```

This call will return you a pointer to your main window (If you did something incorrect, you could have to cycle through the [NSApp windows] array in order to search for your main window).

When you have found the window, send it a orderFront message, by doing (supposing the code above returns the correct window, as explained before).

```
[[NSApp mainWindow] orderFront:self];
```

and the window should magically order front.

Comment: Can you Write some Code please?? I am very new to this..!!I tried what you said but i think i am doing something wrong.. so still not able to make `MainWindow` at front..

Comment: have you tried to send orderfront call to every window in the windows array?